# Build list of ancestors from nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

The nested array looks like this:

```js
var arr = [{
  id: 2,
  name: 'a',
  children: []
}, {
  id: 5,
  name: 'b',
  children: [{ 
    id: 14,
    name: 'b2'
  }]

}, {
  id: 15,
  name: 'd',
  children: []
}];
```

How can I make a list of ancestor elements, from any given element?

For example, if given element has `id: 14` the list should return only the parent:

```
[{
  id: 5,
  name: 'b',
  children: [...]
}]
```

I'm looking to replicate a "breadcrumb" navigation

Comment: For `id: 14`, isn't the parent `id: 5`?

Comment: yes sorry I corrected it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could handover an object which is the parent and search recursive for the wanted `id`.

```js
function getParent(object, id) {
    var result;
    (object.children || []).some(o => result = o.id === id ? object : getParent(o, id));
    return result;
}

var array = [{ id: 2, name: 'a', children: [] }, { id: 5, name: 'b', children: [{  id: 14, name: 'b2' }] }, { id: 15, name: 'd', children: [] }];

console.log(getParent({ children: array }, 14));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

If you like to hand over the array, you could take a nested approach with recursive function.

```js
function getParent(children, id) {

    function iter(object) {
        var result;
        (object.children || []).some(o => result = o.id === id ? object : iter(o));
        return result;
    }

    return iter({ children });
}

var array = [{ id: 2, name: 'a', children: [] }, { id: 5, name: 'b', children: [{  id: 14, name: 'b2' }] }, { id: 15, name: 'd', children: [] }];

console.log(getParent(array, 14));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

If we can assume that only two levels exist (parents and children, not children of children) then the following function `findAncestor()` does what you need. It iterates over all parent elements and checks if they have a child with the relevant ID.

```
function findAncestor(id) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    let obj = arr[i];
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty('children')) {
      if (obj.children.length > 0) {
        for (let j = 0; j < obj.children.length; j++) {
          if (obj.children[j].id === id) {
            return obj;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return null;
}

console.info(findAncestor(14));
```

If you need to handle the case that a child with same ID can occur in several parents, you should use a result array and add all found results to it before returning it in the end.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way,

```
     var arr = [{
          id: 2,
          name: 'a',
          children: []
        }, {
          id: 5,
          name: 'b',
          children: [{ 
            id: 14,
            name: 'b2'
          }]

        }, {
          id: 15,
          name: 'd',
          children: []
        }];


    function getAncestor(obj,id,ancestor){
     if(obj.id===id){
        console.log(ancestor);
     }
     else
        if(obj&& obj.children && obj.children.length)
            obj.children.forEach(item=>this.getAncestor(item,id,obj));
    }

arr.forEach(o=>getAncestor(o,14,{}));
```

Answer (score 1):

The Depth First Search Algorithm - get parent node is:

```
function getParentNodeByKey(obj, targetId, paramKey) {
    if (obj.children) {
        if (obj.children.some(ch => ch[paramKey] === targetId))
            return obj;
        else {
            for (let item of obj.children) {
                let check = this.getParentNodeByKey(item, targetId, paramKey)
                if (check) {
                    return check;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return null
}
```

and code to test:

```
var arr = [{
    id: 2,
    name: 'a',
    children: []
  }, {
    id: 5,
    name: 'b',
    children: [{
      id: 14,
      name: 'b2'
    }]

  }, {
    id: 15,
    name: 'd',
    children: []
}];

let parentElement;
const valueToFind = 14;
const desiredkey = 'id';
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    parentElement = getParentNodeByKey(arr[i], valueToFind, desiredkey);
    if(parentElement)
        break;
}

console.log(`The parent element is:`, parentElement);
```